# Run a bash script on an entire directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that removes the first five lines and last nine lines on a user specified file. I need it to run on ~100 files a day, is there any way to run the script against the entire directory and then output every file to a separate directory with the same file name? Here is the script I am using.

```
read -e file
$file | sed '1,7d' | head -n -9 > ~/Documents/Databases/db3/$file
rm $file
```

I set it up to loop because of so many files but that is the core of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for file in ~/Documents/Databases/db3/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && sed '1,7d' "$file" | head -n -9 > /out/dir/"${file##*/}"
done
```

Assuming the input directory is `~/Documents/Databases/db3/` and the output directory is `/out/dir/`.

Comment: This seems to name "$file" as the complete file path so i cant put it in a new directory.